# Flyway 5.1.0 onwards not supporting SQL single-line comment starting with "--" but not followed by a whitespace

Tags: mysql, database-migration, flyway

I upgraded from Flyway 5.0.7 to 5.1.4 for my Spring Boot application, then tried to run a unit test but it failed at DB migration step.

My Flyway script contains a single-line comment starting with "--" but not followed by a whitespace.

```
--Hello
CREATE TABLE `products` (
  `product_code` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  `product_type` VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`product_code`));
```

I expect to see DB Migration to be successful, as it was in 5.0.7.

However, it hit the error below instead.

```
Caused by: org.flywaydb.core.internal.sqlscript.FlywaySqlScriptException: 
Migration V1__create_products.sql failed
----------------------------------------
SQL State  : 42000
Error Code : 1064
Message    : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '--Hello
CREATE TABLE `products` (
  `product_code` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  `prod' at line 1
Location   : db/migration/V1__create_products.sql (/Users/wai_loon/IdeaProjects/deposits/target/classes/db/migration/V1__create_products.sql)
Line       : 1
Statement  : --Hello
CREATE TABLE `products` (
  `product_code` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  `product_type` VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`product_code`))    

    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.database.ExecutableSqlScript.handleException(ExecutableSqlScript.java:331)
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.database.ExecutableSqlScript.executeStatement(ExecutableSqlScript.java:301)
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.database.ExecutableSqlScript.execute(ExecutableSqlScript.java:243)
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.resolver.sql.SqlMigrationExecutor.execute(SqlMigrationExecutor.java:91)
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate.doMigrateGroup(DbMigrate.java:352)
    ... 59 more
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '--Hello
CREATE TABLE `products` (
  `product_code` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  `prod' at line 1
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:944)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3976)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3912)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2530)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2683)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2482)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2440)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeInternal(StatementImpl.java:845)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:745)
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.jdbc.JdbcTemplate.executeStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:244)
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.database.StandardSqlStatement.execute(StandardSqlStatement.java:44)
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.database.ExecutableSqlScript.executeStatement(ExecutableSqlScript.java:280)
    ... 62 more
```

--

*Note: Also posted this issue on Flyway GitHub, https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/2081.*